# Hudson not recognising the changes + clearcase

Tags: hudson, clearcase, hudson-plugins, clearcase-ucm

I am using ClearCase plugin for Hudson.
I have modified files in ClearCase .
However when I run the Hudson build, it is not detecting any changes.

```
> [workspace] $ cleartool lsview CKD_Delta  
* CKD_Delta            \\ofscvr0341\Views\CKD_Delta.vws   
[workspace] $ cleartool startview CKD_Delta  
[CKD_Delta] $ cleartool pwv -root  
M:\CKD_Delta  
[workspace] $ cleartool lsview CKD_Delta  
* CKD_Delta            \\ofscvr0341\Views\CKD_Delta.vws  
[workspace] $ cleartool startview CKD_Delta  
[M_CKD_Delta] $ cleartool lshistory -all -since 30-oct-12.14:55:58utc+0000 -fmt '\"%Nd\" \"%u\" \"%En\" \"%Vn\" \"%e\" \"%o\" \n%c\n' -nco '"Load \Base_VOB"'  
[workspace] $ cleartool startview CKD_Delta  
[workspace] $ cleartool catcs -tag CKD_Delta
```

When I run `cleartool lshistory since 30-oct-12.14:55:58` in command prompt, it is detecting my modified files in ClearCase.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
 * CKD_Delta \ofscvr0341\Views\CKD_Delta.vws
```

That represents a view storage path, for a view which is started ( as the '`*`' indicated)

Make sure your `pwd` (current directory) is the same when the plugin executed the lshist, and when you are using it in the command line.

Also make sure to be in a vob within your view.

---

If all elements are the same (same path, same view, same vob), check the environment variables, in particular `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`, which must be set correctly (to the main group of the vob or one of its secondary group) in order to access properly said vob.

Check if the account used for Hudson benefit from the same environment variables than the account you are using (successfully) in a command line.

Comment: lshistory is executed from [M_CKD_Delta]. Im running the command from M:\CKD_Delta. Tried the same from inside the vob also by giving view path till the vob. But it didnt help.

Comment: @user1797693 I have edited the answer to mention another point to check.